# FIM Synchronization service not starting Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, user-profile, user-profile-service

User Profile Service and User Profile Synchronization services in Central Administration site is started but FIM Synchorization Service is stopped. When i try to start it, gave me this error 6324:

[image]

And another question, and the rights to replicate changes to the directory should be given before attempting to start the profile synchronization service? Or is it not important? Service on idea should and so it is launched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution to your error:
[Event ID: 6324 FIMSynchronizationService Error](http://e-sharepoint.blogspot.ru/2014/11/sharepoint-fix-user-profile-not-import.html)

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)